# Nodejs connection bug with ip redirection

Tags: javascript, node.js, networking, apache-kafka, node-red

I have a problem with NodeJS (I think) using a kafka node on a node-red instance installed on a RPI3.

Scenario:
I have a cluster with a running instance of Kafka. The real ip of the machine which host the kafka broker is private so I have a public ip with a public port which I can use. Then, the requests are redirected to the broker.

Testing my environment with a broker installed on my laptop (so knowing the real ip of the broker) everything works fine.
Performing an attempt on the real cluster node-red shows the problem described in the terminal:

[image: terminal]

So, I took a look in js file representing the kafkaNode I used and I find this:

[image: js file]

I'm quite sure the problem is in these line and in the use of the ip redirection. Anyway, honestly I'm a newbie of Nodejs and javascript so I don't know if there are some bugs about use of it.
Any ideas?

P.S.: I'm sure that kafka broker is correctly running and installed. the problem is exactly in js.
I also tried to reach the "fake ip" with telnet, and it works fine.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you have in `config.zkquorom` apart from the IP ?

Comment: I put just ip:port. But it is equal when I start the kafka broker on my laptop, and in this case it works fine.

Comment: Can you make sure by logging or something. I assume while using your local kafka broker, you are changing it to something like `localhost:port`.

Comment: Excuse me, I didn't understand. Can you explain what do you mean?

Comment: Ok. Does the IP under the REAL IP mask show the correct IP ?

Comment: And does that IP address have any `http://` before it ?

Comment: the ip used to mask the real ip of the broker redirect to the broker correctly.
there are no http://.

Comment: I thought about the ip redirection. Effectively I'm sure about the mapping between the "fake ip" and the "real ip" is well-performed because to kafka I use the fake ip, but in the terminal screenshot I attached is showed the real one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kafka does not work with default values configured if you use a NAT, VM, or other proxy for "ip redirection" because the clients dynamically discover the private IPs of the real kafka brokers and will try to connect directly to those IP addresses and not just the one you configure in your client for the initial connection and meta-data request.

You need to make sure that the broker is setup to advertise the hostname or IP of the machine doing the redirection or your producers will not work.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: Depends on the version you are running but in the newer releases you set `advertised.listeners` in the server.properties file

Comment: I'm using kafka 0.11.0.0, the latest release

Comment: Then it is advertised.listeners

Comment: I tried to set publicIp as advertised.listeners but the broker is still unavailable when I try to send data to kafka. Anyway now node-red doesn't crash, just show a message to inform that the broker is not reachable.
Obviously the broker is actually running, I proved it using console producer and consumers.

Comment: Can you run console producer from the Raspberry Pi? If it fails then Kafka broker is still not setup correctly

Comment: I can't because I have no installation of Kafka on RPI. 
I tried to use console producer from my laptop and the public ip, and that works correctly. I verified with a console producer on the cluster that the message correctly arrives.

Comment: Just download the kafka tar file distribution and you can run console producer and consumer on the RPI since its just a Java client. I have done this myself so I know it works. librdkafka also works as does node-rdkakfa. It's just a little more complicated to get it to compile correctly.